# Reactive Extensions First Throttled Value

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to return the first value from a throttled stream.

In the code below I expected the value `2` to be returned after around 4 seconds.

Instead what I'm seeing is the value `2` is returned after around 11 seconds. The entire observable doesn't complete until after the `Events` enumerable has completed. Why doesn't `FirstAsync` exit early here? How can I make it work that way?

If I remove the throttle line, only event `1` is written to the console so I assume it's something to do with that which is causing the different behaviour.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            static IEnumerable<int> Events()
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("Event 1");
                yield return 1;

                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("Event 2");
                yield return 2;

                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9));
                Console.WriteLine("Event 3");
                yield return 3;
            }

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            var result = Events()
                .ToObservable()
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                .Select(i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Window complete ({i})");
                    return i;
                })
                .FirstAsync()
                .Wait();
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Observable complete ({result}): {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is outputted:

```
Event 1
Event 2
Window complete (2)
Event 3
Observable complete (2): 00:00:11.1100222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That generator is blocking the code within `ToObservable`

Try this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var events = Observable.Create<int>(async sub =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("Event 1");
                sub.OnNext(1);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("Event 2");
                sub.OnNext(2);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9));
                Console.WriteLine("Event 3");
                sub.OnNext(3);

                return Disposable.Empty;
            });

          
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            var result = await events
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                .Select(i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Window complete ({i})");
                    return i;
                })
                .FirstAsync();
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Observable complete ({result}): {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```